How to allow traffic to a specific external address in EdgeRouter?
I'm trying to set up EdgeRouter to filter traffic for IoT devices. I connect the devices to a separate VLAN, and I have so far set up the rules for this VLAN to only allow the devices to connect to my Home Assistant instance. Following the documentation, I could do this:

HASS_IN: Default action: drop, Interface: HASS VLAN, Direction: in

Allow established/related
Drop invalid
Allow HASS:

Allow
Destination: Interface network=[lan], Port group=hass-port




HASS_LOCAL: Default action: drop, Interface: HASS VLAN, Direction: local

Allow established/related
Drop invalid
Allow DNS/DHCP:

Allow
Destination: Port group=DNS/DHCP





This works. I wanted to add another rule that allows access to specific addresses on the internet. I tried adding another entry to HASS_IN that's similar to the "Allow HASS" entry, but with the address of the NTP servers I want to grant them access to. I also tried to add a similar ruleset but with a "out" direction instead. Neither approach worked.
Unfortunately, Ubiquiti's documentation is really poor in this regard. It has some how-to articles that explain steps to follow, but I didn't find one that would explain exactly what those settings mean.
